# How the select the representative frame when detecting vehicles

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing

I am detecting vehicles from the video (taken with a camera), and the vehicle *detection part works fine*.

My problem is that I should **always extract *only one representative frame* per vehicle**, and not the whole sequence.

As an example, if I have a few seconds of video (and possibly multiple vehicles), my approach currently extracts multiple frames (for every vehicle). Instead, as an output I would like *one representative frame* in which the *vehicle is whole, i.e. well visible*.

I have already implemented an entropy technique on it which makes it better but am still getting too much frames of the same vehicle. Could you suggest a technique which I can use to extract only one frame which contains the whole vehicle and ignore all other frames which contain that (same) vehicle.

I use the following entropy technique in my problem

```
double entropy = 0.0;
for (int i=0; i<histNorm.rows; i++)
{
    float binEntry = histNorm.at<float>(i,0);
    if (binEntry != 0.0)
        entropy -= binEntry * log2(binEntry);
}
```

Comment: Hey! I hope I didn't change the meaning of your question with my edit. I was trying to make your question clearer and more understandable. Please edit it back if I misunderstood something. Also, it wouldn't hurt to add a link, or a short explanation, or at least a full name of the _entropy technique_ which you already tried. Hope you get help! (and happy holidays!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can not give you a full approach, but I might have an interesting suggestion. As soon as you *detect a vehicle*, **start [tracking](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tracking?sort=votes&pageSize=15) it**.

For every detection, you could "remember" the first and last frame of the video where you tracked that vehicle. **You associate every vehicle detection with a series of consecutive frames.** The *beginning* frame would be the one when the detection was made, and the *ending* would be the first frame when the tracking algorithm fails.

Then, you could **select only a single frame for every distinct vehicle you tracked** during your video sequence, with more or less simple approaches:

- select the middle frame of the tracking sequence, as there is a high chance that in the middle of the tracking, the vehicle was well visible
- do matching between several points in the sequence, or just base your decision on the number of features you can still track at a certain frame:  selecting a frame with a large number of trackable/matchable features is probably a good choice
- remember the "quality" of your detection for every frame in the sequence, and select the frame where the detection quality was the best
- depending on the preferences, be mindful to either select one representative frame if the sequences for two vehicles overlap, or purposefully select different frames (possibly from non-overlapping parts of the sequences).

Comment: i was just thinking about the same technique but the only problem i was thinking in this technique was your last point , if in one frame we get two different vehicles than how we know the last frame of 1st vehicle which we are tracking

Comment: We can put a condition on overlaping frame that if overlaping occur than it should select the frame before overlaping frame as the last frame , but the problem is how we know the frame is overlaping frame